# SOQL Subquery with where condition

Tags: salesforce, apex, soql

I'm having trouble to do a nested subquery in SOQL. I am trying to query all records from Obj1 based on all the Names which I need to query from Obj2.

```
Select
 Field1__c
From 
 Obj1
Where
  Field1__c =: inputId2 
  AND
  Field2__c IN : inputFieldValues
  AND 
  Parent__r.Parent2__r.Name IN 
  (Select
       StandardField.Name
    From 
       Obj2
    Where 
       StandardField.Id =: inputId
   )
```

Is it possible to query like this in Salesforce?

Answer (score 0):

Not by Name, only by Id. If you can't get the result you want by directly using lookup/master-detail fields in "where parent__r.parent2id__c in (select standardfieldid from obj2)" you'll need 2 queries.